# Subcaption with Beamer

Tags: beamer, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to use `subcaption` with `beamer`, but I get a series of error messages concerning `subcaption.sty` when I attempt to do so. This doesn't happen in the `article` document class. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{First subfigure}
    \label{fig:a}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Second subfigure}
    \label{fig:b}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}
  \end{subfigure}\\
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

```
Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.


! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly
(caption)                in compatibility mode.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \begin{document}

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.7 \begin{document}
```

Any tips?

Comment: In general don't use floats with figures because they can't shift to other slides (would be awkward anyway) and you also don't need captions as nobody needs to know the number of the figure. Mention somewhere in the frame and that would be much more sensible.

Comment: @percusse No; `beamer` internally deactivates the floating mechanism, so `figure` and `table` don't produce floating objects; one can still use those environment in case one wants to use `\caption`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Oh I didn't know that.

Comment: Your example document works fine here (TeXlive 2013). What error messages are you getting? Is updating your TeX distribution an option?

Comment: There's been new developments with the `caption` package and now `subcaption` and `beamer` are compatible. I added a ermark about this in my updated answer and thought that you might be interested too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Update `caption` version 2015/09/17 v3.3-111

Now, since version `version 2015/09/17 v3.3-111` of the `caption` package, `subcaption` and `beamer` **are** again compatible so the error in the question won't appear and `subcaption` can be used with `beamer`.

### Answer for older versions of `caption`

The error message is produced since when `subcaption` gets loaded the `compatibility` boolean option for `caption` is found to be true, and `subcaption.sty` contains the lines:

```
\caption@AtBeginDocument{\caption@ifcompatibility{%
  \caption@Error{%
    The `subcaption' package does not work correctly\MessageBreak
    in compatibility mode}}{}}
```

which trigger the error. You can prevent this error by using the `compatibility=false` option for `caption` (and keep your fingers crossed (see below)), as in the following exmaple:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{First subfigure}
    \label{fig:a}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Second subfigure}
    \label{fig:b}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}
  \end{subfigure}\\
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, this might produce undesired results in `beamer`'s captions; in fact, with the above document you get the warning

> Package caption Warning: Forced redefinition of `\caption` since the
>   (caption)                unsupported(!) package option
>   `compatibility=false' (caption)                was given. See the
>   caption package documentation for explanation.

The `caption` package documentation also warns against using this option:

> But please note that using this option is neither recommended nor
>   supported since unwanted side-effects or even errors could occur
>   afterwards. (For that reason you will get a warning about this.)

If captions and subcaptions are *really* required for a presentation, I think a better option with `beamer` is to use [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) with its `caption=false` option  instead of `caption/subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[First subfigure\label{fig:a}]{\textcolor{blue}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}}\quad
  \subfloat[Second subfigure\label{fig:b}]{\textcolor{blue}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}}
  \caption{A figure}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remark

It's a very common misconception to believe that the `figure` and `table` environments shouldn't be used in `beamer` (the alleged reason is something like "they might produce objects that will float away"). This is not true; `beamer` internally deactivates flotation, so it is perfectly safe to use `figure` and `table` if you *really* need to provide captions in a presentation.

Section **12.6 Figures and Tables** of the `beamer` manual clearly explains this:

> You can use the standard LaTeX environments `figure` and `table` much the
>   same way you would normally use them. However, any placement
>   specification will be ignored. Figures and tables are immediately
>   inserted where the environments start. If there are too many of them
>   to fit on the frame, you must manually split them among additional
>   frames or use the `allowframebreaks` option.

Comment: Isn't a floating environment within a beamer frame a Latex sin?

Comment: @pluton No; `beamer` internally deactivates flotation. It keeps the `figure` and `table` environments (but, as I said, suppressing the flotation) just to give the possibility to use `\caption`. Another thing is if you *really* need captions in your presentations. It is a common mistake to believe that `figure` (or `table`) inside `beamer` might produce flotation to a different slide.

Comment: @pluton Please read Section **12.6 Figures and Tables** of the `beamer` manual.