# Center subcaption-based tabulars in a beamer frame

Tags: tables, beamer, subcaption

I have several tabulars side-by-side using the `subcaption` package in `beamer`:

[image]

However, as you can see, they are not quite centered.

How can I center the tabulars, so that tabular `RAID5` isn't on the very right and `RAID0` hasn't too much space on the left side?

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
% ...
\frame{\frametitle{RAID-Types}
\begin{table}[!htb]
  \subcaptionbox{RAID0}[.25\linewidth]{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        0&1&2\\
        \hline
        3&4&5\\
        \hline
        6&7&8\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
  \subcaptionbox{RAID1}[.25\linewidth]{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        0&0&0\\
        \hline
        1&1&1\\
        \hline
        2&2&2\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
  \subcaptionbox{RAID5}[.25\linewidth]{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        0&1&P(0+1)\\
        \hline
        2&P(2+3)&3\\
        \hline
        P(4+5)&4&5\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
  \caption{RAID-Types. Each column represents one disk. Each row is a block level.}
\end{table}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [`my answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169255/3954) to [Subcaption with Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125579/3954), it's better *not* to use 
`caption/subcaption` with `beamer`; you can use [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig), with the `caption=false` option, instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{RAID-Types}
\begin{table}
  \subfloat[RAID0]{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        0&1&2\\
        \hline
        3&4&5\\
        \hline
        6&7&8\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}\qquad%
  \subfloat[RAID1]{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        0&0&0\\
        \hline
        1&1&1\\
        \hline
        2&2&2\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}\qquad%
  \subfloat[RAID5]{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        0&1&P(0+1)\\
        \hline
        2&P(2+3)&3\\
        \hline
        P(4+5)&4&5\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
  \caption{RAID-Types. Each column represents one disk. Each row is a block level.}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works better :). How can I add a newline/new row of floats, without destroying the first row? E.g. If I add another subfloat called `RAID4`, then the first row contains `RAID0` and `RAID1` only and `RAID5` goes to row2. I want to keep the structure of row1, however. EDIT: I got it. Adding `\bigskip` and newlines after the first three floats.